# Alternative of out keyword in boo language

Tags: boo

I want to use out keyword in boo language but there is no option related to this keyword. how it can be used in boo language.

Answer (score 2):

Boo doesn't support `out`, but the `ref` keyword, which you can use instead.

Example:

```
def Swap(ref a as int, ref b as int):
    t = a
    a = b
    b = t

x = 1
y = 2
Swap(x, y)
```